# Script returns different results on different machines

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, random, python-itertools

I have Python script - simple genetic algorithm. It generates random sequence from list (list is created with itertools), test it, mutate the best results and generate more random results. It work perfectly on some computers, but on others it does not converge to solution.

I am not allowed to show all code, but there is nothing too special as far I know.

Used libs:

```
import itertools
import numpy.random as random
import copy
```

From random I use randint, shuffle.

What I have tried:

1. change between python random and numpy.random - no change.
2. check version -  it does not work on Python <2.7.x but also on Python >2.7.6 (so far what I tested). So I do not think the Python version is related.
3. I test 64bit and 32bit operation systems - it works on 32bit windows 7, 32bit Ubuntu, 64bit Ubuntu and it does not work on another 32bit Ubuntu! So it also does not seem that operation system matters.

Have anybody run in similar issue? What is next thing to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely there's a bug or a numerical issue that makes the algorithm converge for some inputs but not for others (or, if the algorithm is non-deterministic, depending on the values produced by the random number generator).

Try seeding the random number generator to make the results reproducible.

Comment: It helped me to realise, that issue was not in random number.